# How to define Default path for incluse OR gate in JBPM?

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I wanted to know how to add the default path for Inclusing OR gateway to avoid the runtime exception?

I tried without giving any condition. But it doen't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the process editor the OR gateway has a property called "Default gate" and you can choose the path you want to be the default, make sure to name your outgoing paths to make them easier to identify.